# Zero-g astronaut motion

Tags: astronaut-lifestyle, reduced-gravity-sports

If I am an astronaut on a spacewalk in zero-g, and I reach out and hold onto a pole (sticking out from a large space station) on front of me (with the pole parallel to my head-to-feet axis), and then I twist the pole in the direction of my fingers (around the poles long axis) I should be able to rotate myself around the pole, right? Now what happens when I let go of the pole... Do I start to rotate around my CoM, and also gain a translation at a tangent to where I let go?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes, whatever linear and angular momentum you have immediately before you let go will continue indefinitely after you let go. Basically Newton's first law.

Comment: The post-pole rotation about CoM is a little tricky - there might be some "wrist action" or acrobatic maneuver to rotate around the pole without gaining any CoM angular momentum.

Comment: @uhoh: Not in a spacesuit :) The way to go about it would be to tuck your legs, and as you rotate wrists around the pole, counter-rotate your shoulders so that your body retains the same orientation. Good luck tucking your legs far enough for feet to pass over the pole in a spacesuit though. OTOH tuck your legs and lean onto the pole at your waist level and you might gain rotary momentum without linear.

Comment: You can cope with the unwanted angular momentum by continuously rotating your arms/legs to keep your head and body stationary, though you may get tired after a while. Linear momentum, however, is more of a problem and would require chopping off one or more limbs and throwing them away.